# A reference for Poincaré's type inequality for vector fields

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, inequalities, curvature

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\TM}{T\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\Ric}{\operatorname{Ric}}$
$\newcommand{\Volg}{\operatorname{Vol}_g}$

I would like to find a reference for the following claim:

Let $(\M,g)$ be a closed oriented $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Then
$$
    \int_{\M} \Ric(V,V) \Volg \le (d-1)  \int_{\M}   |\nabla V|^2    \Volg,
$$
for every vector field $V \in \Gamma(\TM)$. ($\nabla$ is the Levi-civita connection).

For $d=2$ equality holds if and only if $V$ is a **conformal** vector field.

For $d \ge 3$ equality holds if and only if $V$ is a **concircular*** vector field.

*A vector field $V$ is called concircular if $\nabla V=h\text{Id}_{\TM}$ for some $h \in C^{\infty}(\M)$. Every such vector field is conformal, but not vice versa.

I am quite sure this should be classic, but I could not find this statement anywhere.